# How to fix import for Chrome web driver isn't accessible on Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

UPDATE: CHANGING JAVA COMPILER VERSION TO 1.7 FIXED THIS, THANK YOU EVERYONE!

I am still new to Selenium obviously, I imported all libraries to my project (downloaded from Selenium official page) and started writing a code (basically followed all steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JNeiGbAgL4)

But when I type:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

I get that the type is not accessible.

My current code looks like this

```java
package selenium_test_package;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LAU {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/sergio/Downloads/chromedriver");‎⁨
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver;
```

I am on mac os.

Comment: Are you using Pycharm?

Comment: no, it is on Eclipse (java).

Answer (score 0):

**===================**
APPROACH #1

from [this reference](https://www.swtestacademy.com/install-chrome-driver-on-mac/)

**Step A: Download Chrome Driver**
You need to go the below address and [download chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for Mac OS.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ07G.png

**Step B: Move the driver to the /usr/local/bin folder**

You should move the driver a path which is defined as a path in your system. You can check them with below command and you will see that */usr/local/bin* folder is defined as a global path on your system.

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2c2m.png

If you want you can add a specific path here and you can move the chromedriver to this folder but as you see, /usr/local/bin folder is defined as a path by default.

Now, go to your downloads folder, find the chromedriver_mac64.zip file and unpack it. You will see the chromedriver executable file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLdy1.png

Now, we can run below command and move the chromedriver file to the /usr/local/bin folder.

```
mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin
```

From that - please proceed with your code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    public class LAU {
        public static void main(String[] args) {    
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    .....
```

**========================APPROACH #2**

[Alternatively](https://www.kenst.com/2015/03/including-the-chromedriver-location-in-macos-system-path/): 
System PATH Setup steps:

1) Download the ChromeDriver executable.

2) Now we need to tell Selenium where it is and for that we have a few choices.To do this:

2.1 Open up Terminal

2.2 Run sudo nano /etc/paths

2.3 Enter your password

2.4 Go to the bottom of the file and enter the path you wish to add

2.5 PATH looks like: `/Users/sergio/Downloads`

2.6 Control-x to quit

2.7 Y to save

2.8 Press enter to confirm

3) To double check, quit Terminal and relaunch it. Run echo $PATH. You should see your newly added path in the stream of other paths already there.

4) Finally, update your tests to run using Chrome and run your tests!

After running your tests, if your PATH isn’t set up correctly you get this helpful message:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
```

Hope this helps.
Best regards,

Comment: I was foolowing your first approach and got an error when I put the command that is used for moving chromedriver to `usr/local/bin` so I went to finder, went to `user/local/bin` and moved it manually. Error still not fixed. I should note that even though I downloaded Selenium from the official website I noticed that I have less libraries then then guy in the video I was watching (don't know if it is a mac vs windows thing) but here are my libraries after importing everything https://imgur.com/G68uAw0